# expanding div link not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have done some research to find a way to use a link to expand/collapse some content. I can't see any problems with my code, but the link does nothing.

HTML code ;

```
echo "<div>";
echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"show\">[Results]</a>";
echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"hide\">[Results]</a>";
echo "<table class=\"results\">";
```

Followed by php to populate table, then close the table and div.

CSS

```
.results, .show {display:none}
.hide:focus + .show{display:inline}
.hide:focus {display:none}
.hide:focus ~ .results {display:block ;
 width: 20em; 
margin-left: auto ; 
margin-right:auto}
```

Comment: What is this? ".hide:focus + .show{display:inline}" and ".hide:focus ~ .results {display:block ; width: 20em; "

Comment: Should it not be `.hide:target` http://jsfiddle.net/eJX8z/